# How to install Eclipse CDT extension for Oracle Pro*C

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, oracle-pro-c

I'm new to Oracle Pro*C. I like to use Eclipse for Oracle Pro*C development.

So, please help me to configure Eclipse CDT extension for Oracle Pro*C development.

Please explain to me how to install Eclipse CDT extension for Oracle Pro*C to Eclipse IDE.

Link:
https://github.com/buntatsu/cdt-proc

Comment: The page you link to has instructions. Have you followed them?